# gst-launch works with fakesink but not autovideosink

Tags: gstreamer

I'm trying to figure out how to create a pipeline in GStreamer (1.4.4) beyond the very simple `playbin` one. I have a stream being fed into a GTK+ `DrawingArea` widget but it's currently letter-boxing it whereas I want to experiment with the video stream expanded to fit the entire widget.

To that end, I've played with the `gst-launch-1.0` app but I'm finding that a `fakesink` at the end seems to work but an `autovideosink` doesn't. The two pipelines are (`X` being an `rtspt://` URI for an IP camera):

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=X ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! decodebin ! fakesink
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=X ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! decodebin ! autovideosink
```

In other words, the *only* difference is the sink itself. It appears that, no matter *where* I place the sink (even if it's just an `rtspsrc location=X ! sink`), the problem still occurs, and that problem manifests itself as:

```
rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:5074:gst_rtspsrc_loop<rtspsrc0> error: Internal data flow error
rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:5074:gst_rtspsrc_loop<rtspsrc0> streaming task paused, reason not-linked (-1)
```

I've tried running at higher debug levels but the output doesn't seems to have any useful information beyond the warnings already given.

Note that both the following commands work okay:

```
gst-play-1.0 X
gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=X
```

But, as discussed, I don't really want a `playbin` since I want to install be own video scaler in the pipeline.

My (albeit limited) understanding is that the `rtph264depay` removes the unnecessary RTSP protocol stuff, `h264parse` decodes the H.264 data, `decodebin` auto-magically selects the correct decoder and the `autovideosink` selects the correct sink for displaying the stream.

I'm not entirely certain how changing something at stage five of the pipeline would affect how stage one works.

So why is it that a fake sink works but the automatic selection one does not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add videoconvert before autovideosink will make it works.

`gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=X ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! autovideosink`

The reason is sink element does not support format output from your decode, thus cause the error "streaming task paused, reason not-linked".

fakesink is different. It simply drops the data, not care about format, so it does not this error.

playbin can play because it automatically add convert element when need.

Comment: Thanks for that, matilda gl. I actually thought `autovideosink` was one of those "magical" ones (like `playbin` itself) that just added what it needed to get it working :-) But, apparently not. I'm out of the office today but will check it tomorrow and let you know how it went.